# 'Zoom in' transition effect from image to content - switching content on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a transition between content and this is the idea for now:

I have two divs:

1. The first contains an image that occupies the width and height of the browser, plus a single button, these are the introduction to the web page;
2. The second contains the actual content of the website;

The idea is that when I click the button, the image zoom in, and after the transition I get the web page content.

My code so far:

```js
const btnEl = document.querySelector(".btn");
const trailerContainerEl = document.querySelector(".trailer-container");
const introContainerEl = document.querySelector(".intro-container");

btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  trailerContainerEl.classList.remove("active");
});
btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
  introContainerEl.classList.add("disappear");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.intro-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: fill;
  object-position: center;
}

.intro-container.disappear {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -ms-transform: scale(2.5);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.5);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(2.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button.btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #2a78d7;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 3px solid #20323e;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}

.trailer-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(228, 223, 224);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.trailer-container.active {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

form {
  margin: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="intro-container">
    <img src="https://www.hoganbakery.com.my/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/lion-office-tower.jpg" alt="">
    <button class="btn">Click to choose items</button>
  </div>
  <div class="trailer-container active">
    <form action="" name="myForm">
      <section class="first-section">
        <h3>Choose Item:</h3>
        <div>
          <input type="number" name="bread" id="bread" placeholder="How many?">
          <label for="">Bread</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="number" name="croissant" id="croissant" placeholder="How many?">
          <label for="">Croissant</label>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="third-section">
        <h3>Do you have account</h3>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="" id="yes">
          <label for="">I have account</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="" id="no">
          <label for="">I don't have account</label>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="commands">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </section>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

My code 'sort of' does this, but what I'm trying to achieve is a bit more complex.

I found a great video that describes my vision, here is the link, from the 21st second https://youtu.be/lRVEOoSA5EI?t=21 .

As shown in the video, I would like to have a similar transition after clicking the button: hold for a second or two, 'zoom in' in a smooth way(almost to look like it's going through the door of the image, like it enters the shop), then my content would appear.

Another problem I have with this code(that I didn't solve by now): because I have `overflow:hidden` on body element, and `position: fixed` on .trailer-container class, I can't scroll down my web page.

I hope this is not too much, I realize it is not that easy to achieve.
I'm learning JavaScript, vanilla, and this is some little project I need to make.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code must be provided *in the question itself*, not only on an external site like PasteBin. Please read [ask] for more.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sorry about that, I saw some questions where members shared their code over codepen or similar websites, so I didn't want to make this question text too long. If that's not a common practice, I will edit the question and add code here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to scale, and add opacity of your image, with css animation, and start this animation and opacity when we click on it, test this code

```
/** style.css :*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100vh;
}
p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
}
#overflow-hide-transition{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#img-transition {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

@keyframes presentationTransition{
    to{
        transform: scale(5);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```
<!-- index.html --> :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="FR-fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body >
    <p>This is the body</p>
    <div id="overflow-hide-transition">
        <div id="img-transition" >
            test for zoom
            <button id="boutton-transition"> clique</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/** script.js: */ 
const overflowHide = document.getElementById('overflow-hide-transition')
const imgTransition = document.getElementById('img-transition')
const buttonTransition = document.getElementById('boutton-transition')
const seconde = 3; 

document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    imgTransition.style.cssText = `animation: presentationTransition ${seconde}s linear `
    setTimeout(() => {
        overflowHide.style.display= "none"
    }, seconde *1000);
    

})
```

Comment: This was very helpful Mohamed, however, if a body content is longer than just 'This is the body', it will show under the intro image. Also I need transition to happen only when the button itself is clicked, like in my code. Helpful idea in your code, just not there yet.